# UV light-induced mutagenesis during gel extraction

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, cloning

this is a very short question I did not find the answer for online, neither on this nor other fora. At the beginning of my cloning protocol, I extracted the band with the sequence of interest directly from the gel upon electrophoresis, and failed to minimise the exposure time of my sample to UV (did not switch off the lamp between cutting of different bands). Now, the gel was sitting in the cast tray the whole while (altogether maybe 30 to 50 seconds), and I wanted to know whether this eliminates the risk of mutagenesis, or at least minimises it, due to the absorption of UV light by the cast tray. Thank you.

Comment: I've imaged gels for a few minutes on UV, then went to cut out bands. I managed to get successful plasmids from them after miniprep. Always check your minipreps for proper gel digestion and confirm by sequencing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you remember the size of your inserts? Mine are about 2.5 kb. I will have them sequenced next week, but was just curious as to whether the cast tray is made of plastic that absorbs UV light.

Comment: The gel tray does not absorb UV, otherwise you wouldn't be able to see the bands in the gel.

Comment: @MattDMo They often absorb a little, when I slide the gel off the tray and put it directly on the transluminator, the bands get brighter. I wouldn't bet on the tray making the difference between damaged and undamaged DNA though.